# pandas: get count within each column based on different arithmetic condition

Tags: python, pandas, count, conditional-statements

I've data frame as below. I calculate percentile based on inputs provided.
I'd like to get count for each column that matches certain condition. For example, get count in `a1 >value1`, similarly `a2 > value2` and other column.

```
import pandas as pd 

    df = pd.DataFrame([[10,11,20],[580,11,20],
        [500,11,20],
        [110,111,420],[11,11,20],[80,91,90],
        [80,91,'NA'],
        [10,11,13],[0,14,1111],
        [20,104,111],[220,314,1000],[200,30,2000],
        [61,31,10],[516,71,20],[10,30,330]],
         columns=['a1','a2','a3'])
```

`calculate and describe column based on input percentile, for columns interested. drop NAs`

```
print( (df[["a1","a2","a3"]].dropna()).describe(percentiles =[0.90,0.91,
    0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99] ))
```

I face certain issues:

1. Column `a3` is removed. How do I save it from being thrown away, but simply throw away that row, or ignore NA?
2. I can get value for each column as:

`print(len(df[(df['a1']>200) ]))`
`print(len(df[(df['a2']>100) ]))`

However, this gets tricky and unreadable when data frame has ~10 columns. How do I get counts in a data frame manner for columns for a condition (`a1 > 100`, `a2>90`, `a3>56` )?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compare by dictionary with keys by all columns names and values for threshold in [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) get boolean `DataFrame`, then for count `True`s use `sum` (because processing like `1`):

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

s = df.gt({'a1': 100, 'a2': 90, 'a3': 56}).sum()
print (s)
a1    6
a2    5
a3    7
dtype: int64
```

**Details**:

```
print(df.gt({'a1': 100, 'a2': 90, 'a3': 56}))


       a1     a2     a3
0   False  False  False
1    True  False  False
2    True  False  False
3    True   True   True
4   False  False  False
5   False   True   True
6   False   True  False
7   False  False  False
8   False  False   True
9   False   True   True
10   True   True   True
11   True  False   True
12  False  False  False
13   True  False  False
14  False  False   True
```

Your solution working well for me if removed `dropna`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

L = [0.90,0.91, 0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99]
print( df[["a1","a2","a3"]].describe(percentiles=L))
               a1          a2           a3
count   15.000000   15.000000    14.000000
mean   160.533333   62.800000   370.357143
std    204.229166   79.165469   596.271054
min      0.000000   11.000000    10.000000
50%     80.000000   30.000000    55.000000
90%    509.600000  108.200000  1077.700000
91%    511.840000  109.180000  1092.130000
92%    514.080000  110.160000  1106.560000
93%    517.280000  115.060000  1191.010000
94%    526.240000  143.480000  1306.580000
95%    535.200000  171.900000  1422.150000
96%    544.160000  200.320000  1537.720000
97%    553.120000  228.740000  1653.290000
98%    562.080000  257.160000  1768.860000
99%    571.040000  285.580000  1884.430000
max    580.000000  314.000000  2000.000000
```

EDIT1: If need comapre quantiles by columns from list use:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

cols = ['a1','a2','a3']
print (df[cols].quantile(0.5))
a1    80.0
a2    30.0
a3    55.0
Name: 0.5, dtype: float64

print (df[cols].gt(df[cols].quantile(0.5)))
       a1     a2     a3
0   False  False  False
1    True  False  False
2    True  False  False
3    True   True   True
4   False  False  False
5   False   True   True
6   False   True  False
7   False  False  False
8   False  False   True
9   False   True   True
10   True   True   True
11   True  False   True
12  False   True  False
13   True   True  False
14  False  False   True
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248104/discussion-between-death-metal-and-jezrael).